# How to compare strings while ignoring specific characters

Tags: java, android

I know there are similar threads on this, but most of them only involve ignoring spaces.

I have to write an app using some poorly written data sheets, so often I have to compare things like this:
Packs, packs, Pack(s), pack(s), pack

These should all be considered equal, as they are all a pack. However, none of the people who made these data sheets communicated with each other so now I get to deal with it.

How can I compare strings while ignoring parentheses, spaces, the 's' character, and also making sure everything is lowercase before comparison?

All I have right now is this:

```
private boolean sCompare(String s1, String s2)
{


   return s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)
}
```

Obviously it isn't much and doesn't do anything other than directly compare two lowercase strings, but I'm not sure the proper approach to get the results I need.

The new comparison function should return true for the examples above, and false when comparing things like: Pack(s) and Case(s), Packs and Case(s), etc.

**EDIT**
Using help from the best answer, I've created a function that suits my needs

```
private boolean sCompare(String s1, String s2)
{
    String rx = "[\\se(s)|s$]";
    return (s1.toLowerCase().replaceAll(rx,"")).equals(s2.toLowerCase().replaceAll(rx,""));
}
```

Comment: How many different root words do you need to compare (eg, pack, case = 2 root words)?

Comment: @Jason Right now it would just be case, pack, box, unit, and bag. It might change tho, so I need a function that can handle anything (by simply removing s, (, ), and space)

Comment: I have an idea to do this with regex, I'm gonna see if it works. If it does, I'll post it as an edit

Comment: You could use a regex, but then you'd have two problems :)

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796412/how-to-turn-plural-words-singular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String REGEX = "\\(s\\)|s$";

    System.out.println("Packs".replaceAll(REGEX, "")
                              .toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("packs".replaceAll(REGEX, "")
                              .toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("Pack(s)".replaceAll(REGEX, "")
                                .toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("pack(s)".replaceAll(REGEX, "")
                                .toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("pack".replaceAll(REGEX, "")
                             .toLowerCase());
}
```

Yields:

```
pack
pack
pack
pack
pack
```

So this should do it:

```
private static boolean sCompare(String s1, String s2) {
    return discombobulate(s1).equals(discombobulate(s2));
}

private static String discombobulate(String s) {
    String REGEX = "\\(s\\)|s$";

    return s.replaceAll(REGEX, "")
            .toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to tweak this if you want it to work for boxes -> box. Your fix will produce boxes -> boxe

Comment: This helps a lot. I will post an edit to the answer with the function I decided to use (a slightly modified version of this)

Comment: Not to mention children, geese and hippopotami.

Comment: Hopefully product quantities won't be recorded in terms of geese lol. I've added an answer that successfully converts boxes, packs, cases, bags, cans, and some others I might need

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that this answers your question :) just add another forbidden character to set and it will simply filter that char too.

```
   Set<Character> forbiddenChars = Set.of('s', '{', '}', ' ');

        String testString = "This Is{ Test} string";

        String filteredString = testString
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                        .codePoints()
                                        .filter(character -> !forbiddenChars.contains((char)character))
                                        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                                                    StringBuilder::append)
                                        .toString();
        System.out.println(filteredString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s1.replaceAll("\\W|s\\)?$", "").equals("pack"); // true
```

or:

```
s1.replaceAll("\\W|s", "").equals("pack"); // true
```

If you don't care about any other **s** character in the string.

**"\W|s\)?$"** will remove everything that is not a word character and any **s** at the end.

If you know there will be no other **s** in the words but the last one, then you can use this simplified expression: **"\W|s"**. It will remove everything that is not a word character and any s in the string.