# Is there a java implementation of Porter2 stemmer

Tags: java, porter-stemmer, snowball

Do you know any java implementation of the Porter2 stemmer(or any better stemmer written in java)? I know that there is a java version of Porter(not Porter2) here :

http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt

but on http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/ the author mentions that the Porter is bit outdated and recommends to use Porter2, available at

http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html

However, the problem with me is that this Porter2 is written in snowball(I never heard of it before, so don't know anything about it). What I am exactly looking for is a java version of it.

Thanks. Your help will he highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Snowball algo is available as a [Java download](http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php)

And from [snowball.tartarus.org](http://snowball.tartarus.org/):

> Feb 2002 - Java support  Richard has
>   modified the snowball code generator
>   to produce Java output as well as ANSI
>   C output. This means that pure Java
>   systems can now use the snowball
>   stemmers.

This is what you want, right?

You can create an instance of it like so:

```
  Class stemClass = Class.forName("org.tartarus.snowball.ext." + lang + "Stemmer");
  stemmer = (SnowballProgram) stemClass.newInstance();
  stemmer.setCurrent("your_word");
  stemmer.stem();
  String your_stemmed_word = stemmer.getCurrent();
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed. Exactly! Thanks for that. However, would you mind editing the code. It should be : SnowballStemmer stemmer = (SnowballStemmer) stemClass.newInstance(); in the second line. Thanks.

Comment: And I have one more query. My input to the stemmer is an array containing english as well as other language words. Since I just want to pass the english words to the English stemmer, and prevent other words being passed to the English Stemmer, how can I check for that. Can you refer me to any link ?

Comment: Hi Bikash, with regards to filtering out non-English words my only  suggestion would to filter using a dictionary map. There are plenty of text file dictionaries you can download, for example - http://www.curlewcommunications.co.uk/wordlist.html - although you will probably want to combine with a US English list too. I'd also recommend checking out the WordNet dictionary http://wordnet.princeton.edu/. I would note that it's much harder to identify individual English words, rather than identify a whole block of text, because with a whole block of text.

Comment: (..continued) like a sentence or paragraph you don't need to identify every word, just the majority. If you only have individual words, out of context, it becomes much harder. Either way, I would actually recommend filtering for English words AFTER stemming - and comparing them against stemmed dictionary words, this way you maximise the likely hood of matching on multiple variations of the same word (e.g. computer, computing, computers -> compute)

Answer (score 4):

```
/*

   Porter stemmer in Java. The original paper is in

       Porter, 1980, An algorithm for suffix stripping, Program, Vol. 14,
       no. 3, pp 130-137,

   See also http://www.tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer

   History:

   Release 1

   Bug 1 (reported by Gonzalo Parra 16/10/99) fixed as marked below.
   The words 'aed', 'eed', 'oed' leave k at 'a' for step 3, and b[k-1]
   is then out outside the bounds of b.

   Release 2

   Similarly,

   Bug 2 (reported by Steve Dyrdahl 22/2/00) fixed as marked below.
   'ion' by itself leaves j = -1 in the test for 'ion' in step 5, and
   b[j] is then outside the bounds of b.

   Release 3

   Considerably revised 4/9/00 in the light of many helpful suggestions
   from Brian Goetz of Quiotix Corporation (brian@quiotix.com).

   Release 4

*/

import java.io.*;

/**
  * Stemmer, implementing the Porter Stemming Algorithm
  *
  * The Stemmer class transforms a word into its root form.  The input
  * word can be provided a character at time (by calling add()), or at once
  * by calling one of the various stem(something) methods.
  */

class Stemmer
{  private char[] b;
   private int i,     /* offset into b */
               i_end, /* offset to end of stemmed word */
               j, k;
   private static final int INC = 50;
                     /* unit of size whereby b is increased */
   public Stemmer()
   {  b = new char[INC];
      i = 0;
      i_end = 0;
   }

   /**
    * Add a character to the word being stemmed.  When you are finished
    * adding characters, you can call stem(void) to stem the word.
    */

   public void add(char ch)
   {  if (i == b.length)
      {  char[] new_b = new char[i+INC];
         for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) new_b[c] = b[c];
         b = new_b;
      }
      b[i++] = ch;
   }


   /** Adds wLen characters to the word being stemmed contained in a portion
    * of a char[] array. This is like repeated calls of add(char ch), but
    * faster.
    */

   public void add(char[] w, int wLen)
   {  if (i+wLen >= b.length)
      {  char[] new_b = new char[i+wLen+INC];
         for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) new_b[c] = b[c];
         b = new_b;
      }
      for (int c = 0; c < wLen; c++) b[i++] = w[c];
   }

   /**
    * After a word has been stemmed, it can be retrieved by toString(),
    * or a reference to the internal buffer can be retrieved by getResultBuffer
    * and getResultLength (which is generally more efficient.)
    */
   public String toString() { return new String(b,0,i_end); }

   /**
    * Returns the length of the word resulting from the stemming process.
    */
   public int getResultLength() { return i_end; }

   /**
    * Returns a reference to a character buffer containing the results of
    * the stemming process.  You also need to consult getResultLength()
    * to determine the length of the result.
    */
   public char[] getResultBuffer() { return b; }

   /* cons(i) is true <=> b[i] is a consonant. */

   private final boolean cons(int i)
   {  switch (b[i])
      {  case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': return false;
         case 'y': return (i==0) ? true : !cons(i-1);
         default: return true;
      }
   }

   /* m() measures the number of consonant sequences between 0 and j. if c is
      a consonant sequence and v a vowel sequence, and <..> indicates arbitrary
      presence,

         <c><v>       gives 0
         <c>vc<v>     gives 1
         <c>vcvc<v>   gives 2
         <c>vcvcvc<v> gives 3
         ....
   */

   private final int m()
   {  int n = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while(true)
      {  if (i > j) return n;
         if (! cons(i)) break; i++;
      }
      i++;
      while(true)
      {  while(true)
         {  if (i > j) return n;
               if (cons(i)) break;
               i++;
         }
         i++;
         n++;
         while(true)
         {  if (i > j) return n;
            if (! cons(i)) break;
            i++;
         }
         i++;
       }
   }

   /* vowelinstem() is true <=> 0,...j contains a vowel */

   private final boolean vowelinstem()
   {  int i; for (i = 0; i <= j; i++) if (! cons(i)) return true;
      return false;
   }

   /* doublec(j) is true <=> j,(j-1) contain a double consonant. */

   private final boolean doublec(int j)
   {  if (j < 1) return false;
      if (b[j] != b[j-1]) return false;
      return cons(j);
   }

   /* cvc(i) is true <=> i-2,i-1,i has the form consonant - vowel - consonant
      and also if the second c is not w,x or y. this is used when trying to
      restore an e at the end of a short word. e.g.

         cav(e), lov(e), hop(e), crim(e), but
         snow, box, tray.

   */

   private final boolean cvc(int i)
   {  if (i < 2 || !cons(i) || cons(i-1) || !cons(i-2)) return false;
      {  int ch = b[i];
         if (ch == 'w' || ch == 'x' || ch == 'y') return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   private final boolean ends(String s)
   {  int l = s.length();
      int o = k-l+1;
      if (o < 0) return false;
      for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) if (b[o+i] != s.charAt(i)) return false;
      j = k-l;
      return true;
   }

   /* setto(s) sets (j+1),...k to the characters in the string s, readjusting
      k. */

   private final void setto(String s)
   {  int l = s.length();
      int o = j+1;
      for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) b[o+i] = s.charAt(i);
      k = j+l;
   }

   /* r(s) is used further down. */

   private final void r(String s) { if (m() > 0) setto(s); }

   /* step1() gets rid of plurals and -ed or -ing. e.g.

          caresses  ->  caress
          ponies    ->  poni
          ties      ->  ti
          caress    ->  caress
          cats      ->  cat

          feed      ->  feed
          agreed    ->  agree
          disabled  ->  disable

          matting   ->  mat
          mating    ->  mate
          meeting   ->  meet
          milling   ->  mill
          messing   ->  mess

          meetings  ->  meet

   */

   private final void step1()
   {  if (b[k] == 's')
      {  if (ends("sses")) k -= 2; else
         if (ends("ies")) setto("i"); else
         if (b[k-1] != 's') k--;
      }
      if (ends("eed")) { if (m() > 0) k--; } else
      if ((ends("ed") || ends("ing")) && vowelinstem())
      {  k = j;
         if (ends("at")) setto("ate"); else
         if (ends("bl")) setto("ble"); else
         if (ends("iz")) setto("ize"); else
         if (doublec(k))
         {  k--;
            {  int ch = b[k];
               if (ch == 'l' || ch == 's' || ch == 'z') k++;
            }
         }
         else if (m() == 1 && cvc(k)) setto("e");
     }
   }

   /* step2() turns terminal y to i when there is another vowel in the stem. */

   private final void step2() { if (ends("y") && vowelinstem()) b[k] = 'i'; }

   /* step3() maps double suffices to single ones. so -ization ( = -ize plus
      -ation) maps to -ize etc. note that the string before the suffix must give
      m() > 0. */

   private final void step3() { if (k == 0) return; /* For Bug 1 */ switch (b[k-1])
   {
       case 'a': if (ends("ational")) { r("ate"); break; }
                 if (ends("tional")) { r("tion"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'c': if (ends("enci")) { r("ence"); break; }
                 if (ends("anci")) { r("ance"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'e': if (ends("izer")) { r("ize"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'l': if (ends("bli")) { r("ble"); break; }
                 if (ends("alli")) { r("al"); break; }
                 if (ends("entli")) { r("ent"); break; }
                 if (ends("eli")) { r("e"); break; }
                 if (ends("ousli")) { r("ous"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'o': if (ends("ization")) { r("ize"); break; }
                 if (ends("ation")) { r("ate"); break; }
                 if (ends("ator")) { r("ate"); break; }
                 break;
       case 's': if (ends("alism")) { r("al"); break; }
                 if (ends("iveness")) { r("ive"); break; }
                 if (ends("fulness")) { r("ful"); break; }
                 if (ends("ousness")) { r("ous"); break; }
                 break;
       case 't': if (ends("aliti")) { r("al"); break; }
                 if (ends("iviti")) { r("ive"); break; }
                 if (ends("biliti")) { r("ble"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'g': if (ends("logi")) { r("log"); break; }
   } }

   /* step4() deals with -ic-, -full, -ness etc. similar strategy to step3. */

   private final void step4() { switch (b[k])
   {
       case 'e': if (ends("icate")) { r("ic"); break; }
                 if (ends("ative")) { r(""); break; }
                 if (ends("alize")) { r("al"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'i': if (ends("iciti")) { r("ic"); break; }
                 break;
       case 'l': if (ends("ical")) { r("ic"); break; }
                 if (ends("ful")) { r(""); break; }
                 break;
       case 's': if (ends("ness")) { r(""); break; }
                 break;
   } }

   /* step5() takes off -ant, -ence etc., in context <c>vcvc<v>. */

   private final void step5()
   {   if (k == 0) return; /* for Bug 1 */ switch (b[k-1])
       {  case 'a': if (ends("al")) break; return;
          case 'c': if (ends("ance")) break;
                    if (ends("ence")) break; return;
          case 'e': if (ends("er")) break; return;
          case 'i': if (ends("ic")) break; return;
          case 'l': if (ends("able")) break;
                    if (ends("ible")) break; return;
          case 'n': if (ends("ant")) break;
                    if (ends("ement")) break;
                    if (ends("ment")) break;
                    /* element etc. not stripped before the m */
                    if (ends("ent")) break; return;
          case 'o': if (ends("ion") && j >= 0 && (b[j] == 's' || b[j] == 't')) break;
                                    /* j >= 0 fixes Bug 2 */
                    if (ends("ou")) break; return;
                    /* takes care of -ous */
          case 's': if (ends("ism")) break; return;
          case 't': if (ends("ate")) break;
                    if (ends("iti")) break; return;
          case 'u': if (ends("ous")) break; return;
          case 'v': if (ends("ive")) break; return;
          case 'z': if (ends("ize")) break; return;
          default: return;
       }
       if (m() > 1) k = j;
   }

   /* step6() removes a final -e if m() > 1. */

   private final void step6()
   {  j = k;
      if (b[k] == 'e')
      {  int a = m();
         if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(k-1)) k--;
      }
      if (b[k] == 'l' && doublec(k) && m() > 1) k--;
   }

   /** Stem the word placed into the Stemmer buffer through calls to add().
    * Returns true if the stemming process resulted in a word different
    * from the input.  You can retrieve the result with
    * getResultLength()/getResultBuffer() or toString().
    */
   public void stem()
   {  k = i - 1;
      if (k > 1) { step1(); step2(); step3(); step4(); step5(); step6(); }
      i_end = k+1; i = 0;
   }

   /** Test program for demonstrating the Stemmer.  It reads text from a
    * a list of files, stems each word, and writes the result to standard
    * output. Note that the word stemmed is expected to be in lower case:
    * forcing lower case must be done outside the Stemmer class.
    * Usage: Stemmer file-name file-name ...
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      char[] w = new char[501];
      Stemmer s = new Stemmer();
      for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
      try
      {
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[i]);

         try
         { while(true)

           {  int ch = in.read();
              if (Character.isLetter((char) ch))
              {
                 int j = 0;
                 while(true)
                 {  ch = Character.toLowerCase((char) ch);
                    w[j] = (char) ch;
                    if (j < 500) j++;
                    ch = in.read();
                    if (!Character.isLetter((char) ch))
                    {
                       /* to test add(char ch) */
                       for (int c = 0; c < j; c++) s.add(w[c]);

                       /* or, to test add(char[] w, int j) */
                       /* s.add(w, j); */

                       s.stem();
                       {  String u;

                          /* and now, to test toString() : */
                          u = s.toString();

                          /* to test getResultBuffer(), getResultLength() : */
                          /* u = new String(s.getResultBuffer(), 0, s.getResultLength()); */

                          System.out.print(u);
                       }
                       break;
                    }
                 }
              }
              if (ch < 0) break;
              System.out.print((char)ch);
           }
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {  System.out.println("error reading " + args[i]);
            break;
         }
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {  System.out.println("file " + args[i] + " not found");
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is available as a part of [MG4J](http://mg4j.dsi.unimi.it/).

See the documentation for [EnglishStemmer](http://mg4j.dsi.unimi.it/docs/index.html?it/unimi/dsi/mg4j/index/snowball/PorterStemmer.html), i.e. Porter2. Use method [processTerm(MutableString ms)](http://mg4j.dsi.unimi.it/docs/index.html?it/unimi/dsi/mg4j/index/snowball/AbstractSnowballTermProcessor.html)

MG4J also gives you java versions of other stemmers. See the [snowball package](http://mg4j.dsi.unimi.it/docs/index.html?it/unimi/dsi/mg4j/index/snowball/package-summary.html). All these stemmers can be used independently.

Comment: there was a downvote to your answer when I last checked, now it seems to have disappeared :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a direct answer, but there are stemmers in many NLP toolkits - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing_toolkits.
There's a related question here [Tokenizer, Stop Word Removal, Stemming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664489/tokenizer-stop-word-removal-stemming-in-java) with several answers that might be useful.

We use [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/) which is written in Java and may provide the functionality. I wouldn't expect the variation between stemmers to be critical if you are working in English.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) [integrates](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Stemming-using-automata-td1919477.html), in one form or another, some stemming algorithms. You may find what you're looking for starting at package [`org.apache.lucene.analysis`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html). I however fear the stemming code to be deeply integrated into analysis components, making as a consequence quite hard its extraction ...

Comment: Last time I used lucene i think it was porter1. Is the newer version offers proter2?

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains snowball stemmer api.It has the porter stemmer2 implementation.
http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/snowball_stemmer.php

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [lightweight wrapper](https://github.com/knowitall/nlptools/tree/master/stem/snowball) I made that is [easy to re-use](https://gist.github.com/schmmd/5869660) and [available on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cedu.washington.cs.knowitall.nlptools%7Cnlptools-stem-snowball_2.10%7C2.4.2%7Cjar).