# Match words like recruit, recruiter and recruitment in Java

Tags: java, nlp, string-matching, opennlp, fuzzy-logic

I want to write a code to match certain words. I don't care about the form of the word, it could be a noun and adding -ing to it, it can become a verb. Eg, add = adding, recruit = recruiting. Also, like recruit = recruitment = recruiter.

In simple words, all forms of the words are equal. Is there any Java program that I can use to achieve this.

I am somewhat familiar to Apache's OpenNLP, so if that could help in any way?

Thanks!!

Comment: have you looked into OpenNLP's lemmatizer or stemmer? A quick explanation on lemmatizing vs stemming is [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) in the paragraph starting with "However, the two words".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a stemmer or lemmatizer. You might want to check out [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) which includes a lemmatizer. You might also want to try the [Porter Stemmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397107/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-porter2-stemmer).

My guess is that these will cover some of the cases but not all of them. For example "recruitment" won't be lemmatized to "recruit." For that, you'd need a more complex morphological analyzer but I don't know of a good existing system.