# Are WordNet and JWNL capable of converting plural-to-singular and ver(ing)-to-noun form?

Tags: java, wordnet

I have a set of words in String format. Some of them is in plural forma, some of the others is in verb(ing form). I am going to achieve; detecting and converting plural word into its singular forma and at the same time, if word is in the ing form, convert verb into its noun form or mostly relevant noun form. I have installed JWNL & wordnet, I have tried to read material in the web. On the contrary, I have not get it whether it is capable of doing this convertion. By the way, actually, I have not found a good document about how to use WordNet and JWNl. So, my reading is totaly done on the third web sites.

My question is that WordNet and JWNL are capable of doing these wish? If yes and you know a good start point/tutorial, please share them, too.

Thanks

Comment: you can use java jwi stemmer in which you can easily do whatever you want to do

Comment: reference: http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with reading about stemming here :

[Wikipedia Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)

Some of the popular stemmers are [Stanford Stemmer](http://dbpubs.stanford.edu:8091/~klein/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/process/Stemmer.html)

and 
[Snow Ball Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/)

Comment: Also look at this question [Is there a java implementation of Porter2 stemmer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397107/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-porter2-stemmer)