# Most light-way library to stem and lemmatise a word in java

Tags: lucene, nlp, lemmatization, porter-stemmer

I have a simple project that needs to achieve this kind of things.

```
Sports - > Sport
Walking -> Walk

and ideally also do things like:

good -> better
better -> good 
person -> people
people -> person
```

Could someone point me to the most light-way library that can achieve this? (I know there is lib like Lucene, CoreNLP etc..) but these are quite HEAVY and I really just need a stemmer / lemmatiser

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with coarse results (like `updates` -> `updat`) and the weight is crucial, use stemming. Take a look at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397107/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-porter2-stemmer) devoted to stemming and providing several options: [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php), [Mg4j](http://mg4j.dsi.unimi.it/docs/index.html?it/unimi/dsi/mg4j/index/snowball/PorterStemmer.html) and others.
There is also [WordNet stemmer](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/api/edu/mit/jwi/morph/WordnetStemmer.html) as a part of [JWI](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/).

If you want more sophisticated results, you have to deal with lemmatization, which also [has several libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java): Stanford CoreNLP (it is not so complicated really) or [CICWN](http://fviveros.gelbukh.com/wordnet.html) based on WordNet