# error unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, error-handling, porter-stemmer

im using the snowball stemmer that can be found here http://snowball.tartarus.org/

and i was using this forum question to use a stemming algorithm for my own project

[Is there a java implementation of Porter2 stemmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397107/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-porter2-stemmer)

i use the given class and use this code given in the previous answered post

```
Class stemClass = Class.forName("org.tartarus.snowball.ext." + lang + "Stemmer");
stemmer = (SnowballProgram) stemClass.newInstance();
stemmer.setCurrent("your_word");
stemmer.stem();
String your_stemmed_word = stemmer.getCurrent();
```

but when i come to use a try catch statement i get this error

```
assmt1/invert3.java:339: error: incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
      try(  Class stemClass = Class.forName("org.tartarus.snowball.ext." +"english"+ "Stemmer");
                  ^
(Class cannot be converted to AutoCloseable)
assmt1/invert3.java:340: error: incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
        SnowballStemmer stemmer = (SnowballStemmer) stemClass.newInstance())
                        ^
(SnowballStemmer cannot be converted to AutoCloseable)
2 errors
```

really not sure how to solve this

Comment: The error message in your title does not appear anywhere in your question. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only classes that implements `AutoCloseable` can be used in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement declarations.

> The `try-with-resources` statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. 
>   A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
>   object that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all
>   objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`, can be used as a resource.

`Class` and `SnowballStemmer` are not `AutoCloseable`. Place it inside try block instead:

```
try {
    Class stemClass = Class.forName("org.tartarus.snowball.ext." +"english"+ "Stemmer");
    SnowballStemmer stemmer = (SnowballStemmer) stemClass.newInstance();
} catch(Exception e){
    //Do Something
} finally {
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: i get these two errors `error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            Class stemClass = Class.forName("org.tartarus.snowball.ext." +"english"+ "Stemmer");
                                           ^
assmt1/invert3.java:343: error: unreported exception InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            SnowballStemmer stemmer = (SnowballStemmer) stemClass.newInstance();
                                                                             ^
2 errors`

Comment: Added catch block