# Remove stop words from the parsed content using OpenNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stop-words, opennlp

I have parsed the document using OpenNLP parser code provided in this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/) and I got the following output:

```
(TOP (S (NP (NN Programcreek)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (ADJP (RB very) (JJ huge) (CC and) (JJ useful)) (NN website)))))
```

From this I want to extract only meaningful words, meaning I want to remove all stopwords because I want to do classification further based on these meaningful words. Can you please suggest to me how to remove stopwords from the parsed output?

Finally I want to get the below output

```
   (TOP (S (NP (NN Programcreek)) (JJ useful)) (NN website)))))
```

Please help me with this, if it is not possible with OpenNLP then suggest me any other Java library for natural language processing. Because my main aim is to parse the document and get the meaningful words only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tokenizer, Stop Word Removal, Stemming in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664489/tokenizer-stop-word-removal-stemming-in-java)

Comment: in that question they suggested to use lucene but i need to use opennlp only

Answer (score 5):

It seems that OpenNLP doesn't support this feature. You will have to do as Olena Vikariy suggests and implement it yourself, or use a different NLP library in Java like Mallet.

An implementation in Java to remove stop words is the following (doesn't need to be sorted):

```
String testText = "This is a text you want to test";
String[] stopWords = new String[]{"a", "able", "about", "above", "according", "accordingly", "across", "actually", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all"};
String stopWordsPattern = String.join("|", stopWords);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:" + stopWordsPattern + ")\\b\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testText);
testText = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

You can use [this list](https://gist.github.com/carloschavez9/63414d83f68b09b4ef2926cc20ad641c) of english stop words.

Alternatively using Mallet you will have to follow the tutorial [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import-devel.php).
The part to remove stop words is defined using a Pipe for this purpose:

```
pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(false, false));
```

Mallet includes a list of stop words so you don't need to define them, but it can also be extended if needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily remove all the stop words from the text before passing it to OpenNLP.

1. Store your stop words in an array
2. Sort the array by word length to avoid issues like deleting "did" before "didn't" and ending up with just "n't"
3. Use a regular expression to remove all the words making sure to ignore case and remove whole words only

Here's how to do it in .NET which you can adopt to Java.

```
public string CleanStopWords(string inputText)
{
    string[] stopWords = new string[] { 
        "a", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "aren't", 
        "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "to", "from", "by", 
        "can", "can't", "do", "don't", "didn't", "did" };

    stopWords = stopWords.OrderByDescending(w => w.Length).ToArray();

    string outputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, "\\b" + string.Join("\\b|\\b", stopWords) + "\\b", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    return outputText;
}
```